# Symfony 3 and MonologBundle - DebugHandlerPass vs AddDebugLogProcessorPass

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I've found this PHP message in the symfony log :

> php.INFO: The
>   Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DebugHandlerPass
>   class is deprecated since version 2.12 and will be removed in 3.0. Use
>   AddDebugLogProcessorPass in FrameworkBundle instead. {"type":16384,
>   "file":"/mnt/400Go/www/sy1/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/DebugHandlerPass.php",
>   "line":14, "level":28928, "stack":[...]

I'm using symfony 3.1.15 and Monolog 2.8+... So the thing should already be removed, no ?

I can see the messages within the DebugHandlerPass class in /vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/DebugHandlerPass.php

In /vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/MonologBundle.php, there are two lines calling the DebugHandlerPass class :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DebugHandlerPass;

$container->addCompilerPass(new DebugHandlerPass($channelPass));
```

But nowhere in the PHP files is a AddDebugLogProcessorPass class...

Maybe a version mismatch. If anyone could give me a hint, that would be great.

Best regards,

MC

Answer (score 7):

Just update your "symfony/monolog-bundle" dependency to the latest 3.0 version, and it will do the trick ;)

https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/monolog-bundle

Regards,

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. I've changed the composer.json file to get the 3.0 version of the monolog bundle. The composer update went well, but I still get the very same message.

Comment: 3.0.1 was released with this fix.

Comment: Thanks for the notification @KevinBond

Answer (score 4):

There is a pending Pull Request, see https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/pull/188.
As soon as such PR will be merged, the deprecation INFO message will disappear.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. I'll check from time to time. Best regards. MC

Comment: It is now merged and available in 3.0.1